# twitter read userTimeLine

Tags: android, twitter, timeline

I'm trying to read user timeline from twitter in android, but no success. The call fails with an exception with code 400 - Http request failed. What's wrong with this code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String key = this.getString(R.string.com_twitter_sdk_android_CONSUMER_KEY);
    String secret = this.getString(R.string.com_twitter_sdk_android_CONSUMER_SECRET);

    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(
                    key,
                    secret))
            .build();

    Twitter.initialize(config);

    final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
            .screenName("twitterdev")
            .build();

    userTimeline.next((long) 0, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
            for (Tweet tweet : result.data.items) {
                Log.d("tweet", tweet.text);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d("tweet", exception.getMessage());
            Twitter.getInstance().getTwitterAuthConfig().getRequestCode();
        }

    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know wht's wrong with this code.
Solved this task with the help of twitter4j library.

```
 ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(key);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(secret);
    builder.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);

    mUnauthenticatedTwitter = factory.getInstance();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                List<Status> statuses = mUnauthenticatedTwitter.getUserTimeline("someuser");
                for (Status st:statuses){
                    Log.d("status",st.getText());
                }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```